# Interview preparation for software testing

Tags: testing

I have one year experience in software testing. I want to go to interview in mnc.
What are the technical level interview questions for a software tester ?
What are the practical questions for a software tester ?
What should I learn for preparing for the interview ?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not within the scope of questions appropriate for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to get help on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name). However, be sure to read each site's on-topic page prior to posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on technologies which are used in specific projects.
For me almost everywhere use will use SQL. So you should be able to write some queries using group by, union, union all, join and other expressions.
Second thing is basic knowledge of unix commands.
Third - knowledge of several test tools and project tools
Fourth - knowledge of several languages, used by automated test tools
Give more detailed question (if you can) so maybe I could help you better

Answer (score 1):

you need knowledge of QA principles, testing concepts, testing processes/Methodology, SQL, UNIX, Defect life cycle, Automation tool, scripting language, STLC,  knowledge of management tools like QC, TFS etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepare some logical puzzles, Testing life cycle, bug life cycle, SDLC, Basic sql quires, Testing principals, testing approaches, sdlc models.